# Want to know what variable(query) is being passed around in the following lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I understand that an array is being declared in line 3.

Line 6 queries the array. But how? I don't see any variable being passed around.

```
$(function(){

    var currencies = ["stack", "over", "flow"];

    // setup autocomplete function pulling from currencies[] array
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: currencies,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
        }
    });

});
```

Autocomplete Search: https://codepen.io/DinhTrieu/pen/PwXqGR/

Comment: Re the [*"What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) dupetarget, I'm not immediately seeing what scope really has to do with this. It's not like `currencies` is used in a closure or something...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think the question is "Why is the `currencies` variable available within the the following function". The answer being; they are declared within the same scope. Maybe I am misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Turnip - It's not used in a function. It's used in a function *call*, but that's not unusual...

Comment: Reopen if you like. I'm still not convinced that the other question doesn't answer this question personally.

Comment: @Turnip - I'll leave it as-is, it's probably not a significant question anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{...}` structure being passed into `autocomplete` is an object initializer; it creates an object with the listed properties in it. One of those properties is `lookup: currencies`, which passes the array into the function as the `lookup` property of the object. So `autocomplete` has access to the array, because it has access to the object with the `lookup` property on it.

Here's a simpler example:

```js
var currencies = ["stack", "over", "flow"];
var options = {
  lookup: currencies
};
console.log("options.lookup[0] = " + options.lookup[0]);
foo(options);

function foo(opts) {
  console.log("in foo opts.lookup[0] = " + opts.lookup[0]);
}
```

Comment: That made sense. Anyway to store the query in a variable?

Comment: @MacDuff - It's not a query, it's just an array, and it's stored in (well, a reference to it is stored in) `currencies`. I suspect `autocomplete` also lets you specify a function that gets called instead, so you can fine-tune what you present. (If it's the one from jQuery UI, I know it does.)